# Instantiating objects if not passed by reference

Tags: c++, oop

I am creating an interface class for a bunch of different other large objects. Since they are large, I am passing them by reference. I am experiencing some problems.

1. How do I have default object creation while still keeping pass by const reference for the objects I do have? In my case, there are in fact n objects that go into the interface (n > 4), and objects 3->n depend on objects 1 and 2.
2. Is there a better way to construct the class? Currently, one needs to call Interface(obj1, obj2...) with n objects in the exactly correct order, and it furthermore it looks like a mess with the required list initialization.

```cpp
class Interface {
public:
    Interface(const Obj1& obj1, 
        const Obj2& obj2,
        const Obj3& obj3,
        const Obj4& obj4) :
        obj1(obj1), 
        obj2(obj2), 
        obj3(obj3), 
        obj4(obj4)
    {}
    // I want this 2nd constructor to create default version of obj3, obj4, etc.
    // Even better if it will be default create any of the object missing,
    // rather than making a separate constructor for each combination of
    // missing objects.
    Interface(const Obj1& obj1, const Obj2& obj2) : obj1(obj1), obj2(obj2) {}  

    // Getters
    mat dat1() const { return obj1.dat1(); }
    mat dat2() const { return obj2.dat2(); }
    // ...


private:
    const Obj1& obj1;
    const Obj2& obj2;
    const Obj3& obj3;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: you store pointers instead of references, pointers can be nullptr, there's no such thing as nullreference

Comment: You can have a `private static` member to which references can be set. You can compare the referred object's address with that member to see if your reference is "unused". But it's really not worth the effort and raw pointer data members, despite all of their problems, are still preferable to references. Reference data members impose annoying limitations on what your `class` can do.

Comment: How are the lifetimes of these objects supposed to be managed? Implementing some sensible scheme for that will likely result in improvements to this code as part of that same process.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this comment?